# AWS secretsmanager error, unable to list the secrets with particular prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I have added some secrets from an EC2 server to the AWS SM using the instance profile with the prefix `mysecrets*`. Now I'm trying to list the secrets that are created in the account, but I get the:

> error user is not authorize to perform ListSecrets operation

The IAM policy allowed the action to `secretsmanager:ListSecrets` and the arn is `arn:aws:secretsmanger:region:accntid:secret:mysecrets*`.

The command that I run:

```sh
aws secretsmanager list-secrets --region us-east-1
```

Error:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListSecrets operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxx:assumed-role/ec2-xxxx-dev-s3-role/xxxxx is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:ListSecrets

Comment: Make sure that the IAM policy with the secretsmanager:ListSecrets permission is attached to the instance profile (instance role) and that this instance profile is on your ec2 instance from where you are running the CLI command.

Apart from that, what you are doing seems to be correct.

Comment: Michael, if I give the permissions to all the secrets in my account...the above command works to list the secrets but I just gave the permission to access particular secrets that are created using a prefix mysecrets* .. so is there any command to list the secrets with particular prefix but not all the secrets

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer:**

Retrieving Secrets by prefix is not supported by AWS (as of Jan 7 2020)

**Here's Why:**

You probably tried to set a resource arn restriction to the policy along with the action `ListSecrets`. This will cause the `ListSecrets` to appear in the policy json but not actually grant to your user.

`ListSecrets` is an all or nothing deal, you can't restrict the arn like you can with `GetSecretValue`.

You could try creating a separate policy attachment or statement without an arn restriction. but if your intent is only retrieve secrets with a specific prefix, this will not happen, it will return all of the secrets (yea, I know, not very scalable)

See this link below for a list of actions you can and cannot associate to a context such as arn:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_iam-permissions.html